# Getting NoSuchMethodError at using Spongycastle with iText on Android

Tags: java, android, itext

I was trying to sign a PDF document with iText on Android. The certificate was included and activated in the emulator. Here are the libraries I used:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/itext-licensekey-1.0.4.jar')

compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.54.0.0'
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.54.0.0'
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.54.0.0'
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pg:1.54.0.0'
```

Following is the class that I used to sign existing pdf document:

```
public class SignPDF {

static {
    Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
}

public void sign(String src, String dest,
                 Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey pk, String digestAlgorithm, String provider,
                 MakeSignature.CryptoStandard subfilter, String reason, String location)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');

    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setReason(reason);
    appearance.setLocation(location);
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");

    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    ExternalSignature signature =
            new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain,
            null, null, null, 0, subfilter);
}

private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
public static final String SRC = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "testdsign_1.pdf"; // consider the file to be created earlier
public static final String DEST = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "testdsign_2.pdf";

public static void signat(Activity a)
        throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(a, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                a,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "keystore.p12";
    char[] pass = "123456".toCharArray();
    BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(provider);
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", provider.getName());
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(path), pass);
    String alias = (String) ks.aliases().nextElement();
    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, pass);
    Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
    SignPDF app = new SignPDF();
    try {
        app.sign(SRC, DEST, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provider.getName(),
                MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test", "Ghent");
    } catch (DocumentException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Finally, the error stack

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(I)V in class Lorg/spongycastle/asn1/ASN1Integer; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1Integer' appears in /data/data/dsign.example.com.dsigntest/files/instant-run/dex/slice-core-1.54.0.0_016eb8590d95a10a91a6367c6ca7de97121683a4-classes.dex)
                                                                           at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7.getEncodedPKCS7(PdfPKCS7.java:826)
                                                                           at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.signDetached(MakeSignature.java:154)
                                                                           at dsign.example.com.dsigntest.SignPDF.sign(SignPDF.java:56)
                                                                           at dsign.example.com.dsigntest.SignPDF.signat(SignPDF.java:91)
                                                                           at dsign.example.com.dsigntest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

What is the cause of the problem? Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: Look at the SC version required by itextg in its pom.xml.  it surely is not 1.54.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse thank you, I will try to change the version

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse it worked, I used SC version 1.47 from [this](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.madgag/scprov-jdk15on/1.47.0.1/) link. Please copy your comment as an aswer below so that I can accept it. Thank you.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I am facing new problem with version compatabilities. In order to sign a certificate with CA SpongyCastle requires 1.55 version, however, using iText is not possible. What can I do?

Comment: See my comment to @leobelizquierdo below.

Comment: @BekaBot I also updated my answer. If you have additional questions, do not ask them in the comments, but instead ask a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse thank you very much for your answers on this question, I started new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209778/signing-a-certificate-using-ca-in-itextg) as you adviced to. I would really appreciate if you helped to resolve that issue.

Comment: Sorry, that is not my area of expertise. I hope you'll get an answer from someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using BouncyCastle version 1.54. iTextG 5.5.* requires SpongyCastle version 1.47.0.2 (meanwhile iText 5.5.* requires BouncyCastle version 1.49).

The recommended way is to add iTextG to your Maven/Gradle/... config as a dependency, and your build tool will automatically pull in the correct version of SpongyCastle, which is currently 1.47.0.2. There is no need to manually hunt for dependencies. Dependency resolution is a solved problem on Android.

EDIT:

Some people apparently don't the Maven build tool (or Gradle), but manually search for jars on http://search.maven.org. If you do that, and you blindly search for "spongycastle", then you will only find the **wrong** version.

As one can see in the iTextG [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/itextg-5.5.10/itext/pom.xml):

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.madgag</groupId>
    <artifactId>scprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.47.0.2</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.madgag</groupId>
    <artifactId>scpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.47.0.2</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

I repeat, these are the correct dependencies for iText 5.5.*:

- groupId: `com.madgag`
- artifactId: `scprov-jdk15on` and `scpkix-jdk15on`
- version: `1.47.0.2`

These dependencies are **WRONG** for iText 5.5.*:

- groupId: `com.madgag.spongycastle`
- artifactId: `prov` and `pkix`
- version: `[1.50,)`

If, after making sure that you use the correct version of SpongyCastle, you still have issues, then you have to ask a NEW question. In your question, include the following information:

- Your iTextG version
- Your SpongyCastle version
- Your POM file or Gradle file
- Output of `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`
- Copy/paste of the error you get.

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue, I'm using itextg v5.5.10. The min spongycastle version in maven is 1.50.0, any idea?

Comment: You are looking at the wrong version of Spongy Castle. Starting from `1.50`, they renamed the `groupId` to `com.madgag.spongycastle`. For `1.47.02`, as you can clearly see in the iTextG `pom.xml`, the `groupId` is `com.madgag` and the artifacts are `scprov-jdk15on` and `scpkix-jdk15on`. I double checked, I currently have my browser open on http://search.maven.org and I can find the artifacts. If you still have issues, start a new question.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day. For some reason current versions of itextg from jcenter or maven got no dependencies added to the pom. I was getting crazy. Adding those com.madgag to my gradle project dependencies did the trick.